# Is the statement true. Let $A$ be NxN matrix with real entries and diagonalizable. One of $A$ 's eigenvalues is purely imaginary, then so is the rest.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this statement true? Any hints how to prove it? I thought of showing that we cannot construct such a characteristic polynomial with real coefficients with at least one non purely imaginary and at least one purely imaginary root for 2x2 case and then use induction, but I don't think that's the best way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Since a real-valued real-diagonalizable matrix can't have pure imaginary eigenvalues, I suppose that you mean complex-diagonalizable.

It seems like you should notice that blocking a matrix with a real diagonal matrix will always append real eigenvalues, while keeping the matrix diagonalizable.

So, for example, what about this:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

It's true for $n=2$ because eigenvalues occur in conjugate pairs for real matrices.

Comment: So you are assuming that "diagonalizable" means over $\mathbb C$, which would not be my understanding of the problem (no mentioned of complex numbers before that point).

Comment: @Ingix A real valued, real-diagonalizable matrix cannot have any pure-imaginary eigenvalues, so what would be the point?  I will add this to the post...

Comment: I know (if $0$ doesn't count as pure imaginary). Either way, the problem seems simple, but I guess your version makes at least a little sense.